# How to access variables changed in method

Tags: c#

I have a method called **processOrders** that takes 3 arguments and it does not return anything.  One of the arguments is named **currentOrder**.

I will need the value of currentOrder after it's been processed by processOrders.

How do I get that value of currentOrder after it's been changed by the processOrders method when that method does not return anything?

Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
var orderTitle = "";
var currentOrder = 0;
var totalOrders = orders.Count;

processOrders(currentOrder, totalOrders, orders);

if(currentOrder > 10) {
  //...do stuff...
}

processOrders(int currentOrder, int totalOrders, IList<Orders> orders)

{
    while (currentOrder < totalOrders)
    {

       if(orders[currentOrder] < 5)
       {
            orderTitle = orderTitle + orders[currentOrder];
            currentOrder ++; 
       } else {
             yield return
               CreateNewOrderForm(currentOrder, orderTitle)
             break;
       }  

   }

}
```

Comment: either change the method signature to return an `Int` or change the parameter to be an `out parameter`

Comment: what is an out parameter?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting too technical...   The standard way of passing primitives (like "int" or "decimal") is to pass them by value.  That means you pass the value in to the function and a new "copy" of the variable is made inside the function.  That copy is only manipulated inside of the function, and is destroyed when the function exits.

If you want to manipulate the variable within the function and keep those changes, you will want to pass by reference.  Passing by reference means that you give the function a "pointer" to your variable, and if the function makes any changes to the value, it will change your copy of the variable, the one it has a reference to.

To accomplish this, you must declare the parameter as a reference parameter, and then also call the function with a reference.  Like this:

```
public void processOrders(ref int currentOrder, int totalOrders, IList<Orders> orders)
{
    //...
}

public void main(int[] args)
{
   //....
    processOrders(ref currentOrder, totalOrders, orders);
    if(currentOrder > 10)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly pass your list of orders by reference because objects are, by default, passed by reference.

Comment: Here is some more info on passing by reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: It's true that in this situation, you aren't really passing anything IN to the function for currentOrder, so it could be an out parameter just as easily as a ref parameter.  The two are similar, but ref allows you to pass a value in and read any change to it.  An out parameter is one direction only, and MUST be set before the function exits.